# REndering Pageblock table based on condition

Tags: visualforce, rendered

[image] 
Rendering Page Block table based on condition

I have 2 pageblocktables. Pageblocktable1 renders if List contains value. Pageblocktable2 renders if List doent contains value.

trying out this

None of them working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not use braces for the function `size`:

```
rendered="{!list.size > 0}"
```

2) Use `ISBLANK` function to check an expression for the NULL:

```
rendered="{!ISBLANK(list)}"
```

Here more info about functions: [Operators and Functions](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISBLANK)

Comment: Its giving error
Save error: Unknown function lstApplication.size. Check spelling. test2.page /OAOA Project1/src/pages line 0 Force.com save problem

Comment: @TestNS What kind of variable is the `lstApplication`? You can use `.size` only for the lists.

Comment: It worked fine now thans. I was also using opening and close brackets